# Where did Kylo Ren learn how to make a crossguard lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, kylo-ren

I'm aware the design is an old one, not something Kylo came up with himself, and doesn't even always correlate to a cracked crystal (the Malachor crossguard saber seemed fine).

So, where did Kylo Ren learn how to build a crossguard saber? Was it something Luke taught him? Snoke? Do we just not yet know?

Comment: I feel like we don't know yet. We may find out with TLJ, though :)

Comment: There's plenty of guides on the Internet. For instance: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the crossguard lightsaber design was part of the Jedi tradition. In *Star Wars Rebels*, Ezra and his friends entered the Great Scourge site on Malachor and discovered such a weapon. Perhaps Luke found the design after the fall of the Empire and shared the information with Kylo.

[image]

Wookieepedia [says](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Scourge_of_Malachor):

> The Great Scourge of Malachor was first referenced in the 2015
>   reference book Star Wars: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary,
>   which stated that the crossguard design of Kylo Ren's lightsaber was
>   an ancient one that dated back thousands of years to the Great Scourge
>   of Malachor. The book's author, Lucasfilm Story Group creative
>   executive Pablo Hidalgo, added the reference to the book to connect it
>   with the battle that was ultimately referenced in "Twilight of the
>   Apprentice," the second season finale of the animated television
>   series Star Wars Rebels.

On the other hand, however, it is not certain Kylo constructed the lightsaber himself...